# How to avoid extra space when using glyphicon with text?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I've a div with text in div.But the weird behavior occurs when glyphicon is added,that is spacing between the words has become more.

How to avoid this ?

```
<div class="glyphicon  glyphicon-chevron-up">With glyphicon</div>
<div>Without glyphicon</div>
```

<kbd>[**Demo of the issue**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/6ywd9tew/1/)</kbd>

<kbd>[**Demo of Implementation in my application**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/txu06qtk/)</kbd>

Comment: you are using it wrong, the `<div class="glyphicon  glyphicon-chevron-up"></div>` must be empty, used like `<img src="" alt="" / >` with text after or before, not inside;

Comment: As stated in the [Bootstrap How To](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use), _"Don't mix with other components"_ and _"Only for use on empty elements"_.

Comment: @xpy thanks for that info,that was the only solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one works...

```
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></div>With glyphicon
<div>Without glyphicon</div>
```

If you can't use this then use this one :

```
 <div class="glyphicon  glyphicon-chevron-up" style="color: steelblue;font-size: initial;" data-toggle="collapse"   href="#new"></div><span style="color: steelblue;font-size: initial;" href="#new">
Glyhicon div with collapse</span>
<div class="collapse in" id="new">
Something goes here
</div>
```

Then you only have option to click on icon to toggle.

Comment: this will not work in my case as I toggle glyphicon with chevron-down using  collapse,As the whole div needs `data-toggle="collapse"`

Comment: You need to put the entire div accordingly, then we can see whats the real issue

Answer (score 1):

You can add a span for the Glyphicons

```
<div><span class="glyphicon  glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>With glyphicon</div>
<div>Without glyphicon</div>
```

It works well and its a good practice to add a separate span for the glyphicons.
What is happening in your code is that the **glyphicon** class property is being applied to the content that you are writing within the **div** tag.

Answer (score 0):

`glyphicon` class applies the `font-family : 'Glyphicons Halflings'` in which the symbol can be rendered. But you have added your text inside same `<div>`. So that font will be applied to your text too. I have moved the text to another `<span>` and applied the desired `font-family : 'sans-serif'` to the text.Which solves the issue OR simply move your text out of that `<div>`, that too will work

With glyphicon
    Without glyphicon

**New Class**

```
.newFont{
      font-family: sans-serif
}
```

[JdFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nofiden/6ywd9tew/2/)

Comment: no need to introduce a new class; OP is just using them incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the text and you want to write text inside glyphicon you should add to bootstrap glyphicon class the before attribute so it gives effect only to the before like this :

```
  /*add the :before to glyphicon */

      .glyphicon:before  {
      position: relative;
      top: 1px;
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      line-height: 1;

      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
```